# error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++

I have problem with my code. Whenever I try to print out two strings together as a result it shows an error.
I even tried to change quotation marks from " " to ' ' -  but it still doesn't work and show negative number . What is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename R>

auto sum(T a, R b)
{
    return a + b;
}



int main()
{


    cout << sum("hello", "world") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: These are not strings, but `const char*` ;)

Comment: Don't obfuscate things for yourself with the template. Does it work when adding directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can not sum pointers like this. If you want to concatenate two char pointers you can use [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) or better [strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/?) (that helps you avoid overflow of the buffer).

Better yet if you really do use `c++` simply use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) where this sort of arithmetic is handled for you.

Comment: `strncat` and other "n" variants like it fail to null terminate the string if it reaches the length of the destination buffer and if they don't, they zero out the rest of the destination buffer. Whether the destination buffer was big enough or not, you pay an additional cost. And since you always have to manually make sure the result is null terminated, you lose the benefit of a safe clean alternative.

Comment: @Bardo23 Because `"hello"` is not a string, it's a string literal. Type of `"hello"` is `const char[6]`. If you want string, use `sum(std::string("hello"), std::string("world"))` or with C++14 `sum("hello"s, "world"s)` (you need `using namespace std::string_literals` beforehand to make this literal visible)

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `"hello"` and `"world"` they're not `strings`, they are arrays of `const char`'s that don't support concatenation.

You can use a template specialization `sum` if you need to sum `const char` arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<typename T, typename R>
auto sum(T a, R b)
{
    return a + b;
}

auto sum(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    return string(a) + string(b);
}

int main()
{

    cout << sum("hello", "world") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or modify the parameters to make them strings that can be concatenated with the operator `+`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<typename T, typename R>
auto sum(T a, R b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{

    cout << sum(string("hello"), string("world")) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How ' const char* ' work. Because It's working but I don't know why.

Comment: `const char*` is just a pointer to the position of a read-only array of characters. It doesn't have methods or support concatenation by itself.